# Sum of all column name of specific string dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table wherein I want to get the total prices of a column in specific dates. The dates are strings `(eg: January 2018)`. What I have tried is to convert the string to date.

```
SELECT
    SUM(price_amount) as 'total_paid',
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ',price_month), "%M %d %Y") as dates
FROM user_prices
WHERE price_type = 'cash' AND price_month >= DATE('January 01 2018')
GROUP BY price_month
ORDER BY price_month DESC;
```

The result of this is null.  I have to get only the sum of each existing month in the table that dates are equal or greater January 01 2018. And also group them by month.

```
email          price_amount      price_month     price_type    date_added
1@gmail.com     200              April 2017      cash          ---
19@gmail.com    400              December 2017   cash          ---
12@gmail.com    100              January 2018    cash          ---
123@gmail.com   230              January 2018    cash          ---
1234@gmail.com  250              January 2018    credit        ---
321@gmail.com   200              April 2018      cash          ---
32@gmail.com    120              March 2018      cash          ---
```

So the example above should show the expected result below:

```
price_month     total_paid
March 2018      120
April 2018      200
January 2018    330
```

Comment: Is the `price_month` column actually text, or are you just displaying those dates in this way?

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then get back to us.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its a text - varchar

Comment: Your concatenation creates a pattern 'd M Y'; for the conversion you specify 'M d Y' (and you use the wrong type of quotes) - you need to use matching patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `price_month` column is actually literal text as you have shown us, then you'll need to use `STR_TO_DATE` to make this query work.  Note that `STR_TO_DATE` requires at least year, month, *and* day information in order to generate a date.  So, in the query below, I arbitrarily build each month year data as occurring on the first of the month.

```
SELECT
    price_month,
    SUM(price_amount) AS total_paid
FROM user_prices
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', price_month), '%d %M %Y') >= '2018-01-01' AND
    price_type = 'cash'
GROUP BY
    price_month,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', price_month), '%d %M %Y')
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', price_month), '%d %M %Y');
```

[image]

### Demo

Moving forward, please **don't** store your dates as text like this.  In general, you may assume that a puppy gets run over every time you have to use `STR_TO_DATE` in a MySQL query.

Comment: if I change the column type to `date` does it change the values saved on the database?

Comment: @xkev Yes and no.  If you use bona fide dates, which you _absolutely_ should be doing, you wouldn't be storing the actual month names anymore.  But, you can easily generate those again use `DATE_FORMAT`, which goes the other way, and takes a date to generate a string output.  Bottom line is you should move away from storing dates like this.  Instead of `January 2018`, store `2018-01-01` as a date.